# How can I troubleshoot a segmentation fault when working with Python Ctypes and C++?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

Let's say I have the following two function signatures in C++:

```
BYTE* init( BYTE* Options, BYTE* Buffer )
```

and:

```
int next( BYTE* interface, BYTE* Buffer )
```

The idea is that I first initialize an `Interface` class in C++, then subsequently call the `next` function from Python, with a reference to that class.

The first function returns a `BYTE` pointer to the Interface via:

```
Interface*  interface;
// initialize stuff
return((BYTE*) interface);
```

I call it in Python like this:

```py
class Foo:
  def init(self, data):
    # left out: setting options_ptr
    buf = (c_ubyte * len(data.bytes)).from_buffer_copy(data.bytes)
    init_fun = getattr(self.dll, '?init@@YAPAEPAE0HH@Z')
    init_fun.restype = POINTER(c_ubyte)
    self.interface_ptr = init_fun(options_ptr, buf)
    # this works fine!

  def next(self, data):
    # create buf from other data
    buf = (c_ubyte * len(data.bytes)).from_buffer_copy(data.bytes)
    next_fun = getattr(self.dll, '?next@@YAHPAE0HN@Z')
    ret = next_fun(self.interface_ptr, buf)
    # I randomly get segmentation faults here
```

I call this from outside with, e.g.:

```py
foo = Foo()
foo.init(some_data)
foo.next(some_other_data)
# ...
foo.next(some_additional_data)
```

Now, when I run it, I get segmentation faults:

```
[1]    24712 segmentation fault  python -u test.py
```

Sometimes it happens after the first call to `.next()`, sometimes it happens after the eleventh call to `.next()`—totally at random.

There is a C++ test code for the API that works something like this:

```cpp
BYTE Buffer[500000];
UTIN BufSize=0;
BYTE* Interface;

# not shown here: fill buffer with something
Interface = init(Buffer);
while(true) {
    # not shown here: fill buffer with other data
    int ret = next(Interface, Buffer);
}
```

---

Now, as I cannot show the exact code, since it's much bigger and proprietary, the question is: **How can I troubleshoot such a segmentation fault?** I can break when the exception is thrown (when debugging with VS2012), but it breaks here:

[image]

Clearly, that's not useful because nothing is actually done with any buffer at the indicated line. And the variable values are cryptic too:

[image]

In my case `data` is a [BitString](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitstring/3.1.3) object. Could it be the problem if the C++ code does memory operations on the buffer passed? Or that some data is garbage-collected by Python when it's still needed?

More generally, **how can I ensure not getting segmentation faults when working with Ctypes?** I know that the underlying DLL API works fine and doesn't crash.

---

**Update:** When I make `buf` an instance variable, e.g. `self._buf`, I get a segmentation fault, but it breaks at a different location during debugging:

[image]

Comment: Don't hard code mangled C++ names. They aren't standard and vary across platforms and compilers. Declare functions in your C API as `extern "C"`.

Comment: Does `init` make a copy of the buffer? If not you need to hold a reference to it in Python.

Comment: could it be that you're copying a bigger buffer into a smaller one?

Comment: @deW1 No, because I create a completely new buffer with the length of the data. And the error occurs in the DLL, not in Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were a few misunderstandings I had, all of which led to the problems:

- When you create a Ctypes object in Python and pass it to a C function, and that Python object is no longer needed, it is (probably) garbage-collected and no longer in the memory stack where C expects it to be.

  Therefore, make the buffer an instance variable, e.g. `self._buf`.
- The C functions expect the data to be mutable. If the C functions do not actually copy the data somewhere else but work on the buffer directly, it needs to be mutable. The Ctypes documentation specifies this:

  > Assigning a new value to instances of the pointer types c_char_p, c_wchar_p, and c_void_p changes the memory location they point to, not the contents of the memory block (of course not, because Python strings are immutable).
  >
  > You should be careful, however, not to pass them to functions expecting pointers to mutable memory. If you need mutable memory blocks, ctypes has a `create_string_buffer()` function which creates these in various ways. The current memory block contents can be accessed (or changed) with the `raw` property; if you want to access it as `NUL` terminated string, use the `value` property:

  So, I did something like this:

```py
    self._buf = create_string_buffer(500000)
    self._buf.value = startdata.bytes
```

- The buffer should be used in Python like a normal array as shown in the example code, where it's filled and data inside is manipulated. So, for my `.next()` method, I did this:

```py
    self._buf.value = nextdata.bytes
```

Now my program runs as expected.

Comment: You can also create the buffer using `(c_char * 500000)()`. FYI, the `value` attribute is normally only present for simple types such as `c_int` and `c_char_p`. Obviously it also gets added to `c_char` and `c_wchar` arrays, but not to other array types, i.e. it's not available on a `c_ubyte` array.