# Why do I get a segmentation fault here? [Python ctypes]

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I'm very new to ctypes, and I'm getting an error with the simple program below.

foo.cpp

```cc
class Foo {
public:
    int bar;
    Foo(int bar): bar(bar) {}
};

extern "C" {
    Foo * Foo_new(int bar) {
        return new Foo(bar);
    }

    int Foo_bar(Foo *foo) {
        return foo->bar;
    }
}
```

foo.py

```py
import ctypes

libfoo = ctypes.CDLL('libfoo.so')


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.foo = libfoo.Foo_new(bar)

    def bar(self):
        return libfoo.Foo_bar(self.foo)


foo = Foo(5)
print(foo.bar())
```

The segmentation fault happens when I call `libfoo.Foo_bar(self.foo)`, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29673708/2770572), I thought all I needed to do was make a strong reference via `self.foo` so that it wasn't garbage collected.

My guess is that `Foo` is made on the stack in the CPP file, so it's immediately wiped after the function call is made. In any case, how do I fix this?

Comment: ctypes has no idea what any of these functions take or return. For example, it has no idea what a `Foo *` is and no idea that `Foo_new` returns one.

Comment: Garbage collection comes into play for ctypes callbacks, not for a pointer to an object that has nothing directly to do with Python. It's segfaulting here because the default integer result type and argument conversion is a 32-bit C `int`, which will truncate a 64-bit pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to explicitly wrap the arguments and return types, otherwise `ctypes` will assume some arbitrary defaults which might or might not work.  To wrap the pointer to the class `Foo`, I'd use a pointer to void `c_void_p`.  I'm unsure whether this is the correct approach, but it seems to work.

```python
import ctypes

libfoo = ctypes.CDLL('libfoo.so')

libfoo.Foo_new.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]
libfoo.Foo_new.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

libfoo.Foo_bar.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
libfoo.Foo_bar.restype = ctypes.c_int

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.foo = libfoo.Foo_new(bar)

    def bar(self):
        return libfoo.Foo_bar(self.foo)

foo = Foo(5)
print(foo.bar())
```

---

I usually take a different path to interface C++ code with Python by generating a Python extension using SWIG.  Therefore I would write in a file `test.h`

```c++
class Foo {
public:
    int bar;
    Foo(int bar): bar(bar) {}
};
```

Then I would write a SWIG interface file `test.i`

```c++
%module test
%{
#include "test.h"
%}
%include "test.h"
```

Then I execute in the terminal

```bash
$ swig -python -c++ test.i
$ c++ -fpic -shared -I/usr/include/python2.7 test_wrap.cxx -o _test.so
```

And then I can write in a Python script

```python
from test import Foo
foo = Foo(5)
print foo.bar
```

Comment: `c_void_p` isn't very type safe in general, compared to using an opaque struct pointer. However it doesn't matter in this case since the `foo` instance is encapsulated data.